# How to properly use lists here?

Tags: python, list

My issue is as follows: I want to create a program that accepts a random list (`l`) from the list. This randomly chosen list, in its turn, contains other lists. Then it should find the shortest list inside `l` and cut all other lists inside `l` by the length of the shortest one. These lists should be appended to a new list (`l_exit`) as follows: [`l[1][1]`, `l[2][1]`, ... , `l[i][1]`, `l[1][2]`, ... , `l[i][k]`]. Then all elements, which have been cut, should be added to the end of `l_exit`.

**Input**: `[[1,2,3],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]]`

**Output**: `[1, 'a', 30, 2, 'b', 40], [3, 50, 60]`

> (shortest length is 2 (`['a','b']`). we cut every list by 2 and
> therefore have new following lists `[1,2],['a','b'],[30,40]`. They are
> added accordingly to `l_exit[0]` (firstly go first elements of each
> list, secondly - second and so on). In the end we add a new list of
> items that have been left, that have been cut from pre-existing lists: `3,50,60`)

When I try running the program with above-mentioned input, I have the following output:

```
changed l: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]]
l_exit: [[40, 'b', 2, 30, 'a', 1, 1],[]]
```

What can be the source of the problem? I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

The program:

```
import random
l_1 = [[1,2,3],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]] 
l_2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],['a', 'b','c'], [30, 40, 50, 120]] 
l_3 = [[1],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60, 101, 120]] 
l_rand = [l_1,l_2,l_3]
l = random.choice(l_rand)
l_exit = [[],[]]

if (len(l[1]) < len(l[2])):
  index = len(l[1])
else:
  index = len(l[2])

for i in range (len(l)):
  if (len(l[i]) < index):
    l_exit[1] = l[i][index:]
    l[i] = l[i][:index]

for i in range (index):
  for k in range(len(l)):
    l_exit.insert(0,(l[k][i]))

print('changed l:', l)

print('l_exit: ', l_exit)
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You should debug your code, see what is happening lline-by-line and find out after which line is a value wrong (i.e. not what you would expect). Then you will probably have an answer. And if then you don't understand why that line of code produces an unexpected result, then you will have a proper question.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function to get your first part. First we 'unpack' using the `*`, then we loop over the lists:

```
x = [[1,2,3],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]]

out = [] 
for i in zip(*x):
    out.extend([*i])
out
#[1, 'a', 30, 2, 'b', 40]
```

`zip` finishes at the shortest element, so we are done.

To get the remainder list, we can do a little extra work to figure out where we finished, using a counter, and then subset the original lists:

```
out = []
left = []
count = 0

for i in zip(*x):
    out.extend([*i])
    count += 1
    
for i in x:
    left.extend(i[count:])

out, left
#([1, 'a', 30, 2, 'b', 40], [3, 50, 60])
```

Comment: Tysm, @jeremycg !

Answer (score 1):

**Defining `index`**

Firstly, there is an issue in the following `if`/`else` tree:

```py
if (len(l[1]) < len(l[2])):
  index = len(l[1])
else:
  index = len(l[2])
```

What happens in the case that `l[0]` is the shortest `list` within `l`? Or cases in which the longest `list` within `l` has an index `>2`?

If `index` is to be defined as "An integer representing the `len` of the shortest `list` stored within `l`" then I would suggest the following:

```py
index = len(sorted(l, key=len)[0])
```

The code is quite concise and basically runs as "The value of `index` is the `len` of the first `list` stored in a copy of `l` that has been sorted by `len`". This will stop unexpected/undesirable behaviour that may be generated by your original `index` definition as discussed above.

**Populating `l_exit`**

As far as I understand, `l_exit` should be a `list` containing:

1. A `list` containing all values up to (but not including as to account for index from `0`) the index of `index` from each `list` within `l` - stored in `l_exit[0]`
2. A `list` containing all values from the index of `index` from each `list` within `l` -  stored in `l_exit[1]`

First you try to populate `l_exit[1]` using the following loop:

```py
for i in range (len(l)):
  if (len(l[i]) < index):
    l_exit[1] = l[i][index:]
    l[i] = l[i][:index]
```

The problem here is that given `index` refers to a value that is the shortest `len` of an element in the top-level of the `list` `l` (as discussed previously this may not be reliable in the current implementation but would be in the example output you provided), the code held in the `if len(l[i]) < index):` block will never execute - since by definition no `len(l[i]) for i in l` could be `< index`.

**Conclusion**

I won't go into further detail on issues within your code here as I feel it is obvious that you should spend some time reviewing each statement/structure, debugging with a debugger or console printouts as best fits your attitude - could you state what each line of your code is doing if asked?

I would however recommend looking into the built-in `enumerate()` method - [`enumerate` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - as I feel that you might be able to use this to good effect as to improve the readability/maintainability of your code.

**Solution**

I think it would be time well spent to review your existing code yourself, but for what it's worth here's my full solution to the problem posed.

```py
import random
l_1 = [[1,2,3],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]] 
l_2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],['a', 'b','c'], [30, 40, 50, 120]] 
l_3 = [[1],['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60, 101, 120]] 
l_rand = [l_1,l_2,l_3]
l = random.choice(l_rand)

index = len(sorted(l, key=len)[0])

l_exit = [[j for i in l for j in i[:index]], [y for x in l for y in x[index:]]]

print(f'l: {l}')
print(f'l_exit: {l_exit}')
```

**Test Output**

```
l: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [30, 40, 50, 60]]
l_exit: [[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 30, 40], [3, 50, 60]]
```